# Error Updating code on github: fatal: TaskCanceledException encountered

Tags: git, github, async-await

I added my updated code (just added async-await functionality to my code) using the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push origin master
```

It shows the following errors.

```
fatal: TaskCanceledException encountered.
   A task was canceled.
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Suvendu97/codeile.git/'**
```

Comment: So what is the question? Authentication failed it seems.

Comment: I logged in again, using my username and password, still showing the same

Comment: ok,pushed those codes again, it resolved now